# Как получить длину сгрупированного массива массива?

Tags: javascript

```js
 const arr= [
     {name:"Вася",room:"1000"},
     {name:"Лена",room:"1000"},
     {name:"Катя",room:"1001"},
     {name:"Дима",room:"1001"},
     {name:"Коля",room:"1000"},
     {name:"Костя",room:"1003"}
     ];
 let newarr= arr.reduce((e, i) => ((e[i.room] = e[i.room] ||  []).push(i), e), {});
 console.log(newarr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 const arr= [
     {name:"Вася",room:"1000"},
     {name:"Лена",room:"1000"},
     {name:"Катя",room:"1001"},
     {name:"Дима",room:"1001"},
     {name:"Коля",room:"1000"},
     {name:"Костя",room:"1003"}
     ];
 let newarr= arr.reduce((e, i) => ((e[i.room] = e[i.room] ||  []).push(i), e), {});
 console.log(Object.keys(newarr).length);
```

Comment: да я не успеваю за тобой ))) Пойду лучше чая тогда попью!